# What does it mean to write arguments outside function brackets?

Tags: r, function

My doubt surges as I have the following function:

```
makeVector <- function(x = numeric()) {
    m <- NULL
    set <- function(y) {
            x <<- y
            m <<- NULL
    }
    get <- function() x
    setmean <- function(mean) m <<- mean
    getmean <- function() m
    list(set = set, get = get,
         setmean = setmean,
             getmean = getmean)
}
```

In the instruction `get <- function() x` I dont understand why x is written outside the brackets Is this kind of abbrevaition or something?

Comment: `x` is not an argument of `get`. Since this `makeVector` function is from an exercise about closures, you should study scoping in R: [link](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Scope-of-variables).

Comment: All function arguments are inside the parens. The `get` function defined here has no arguments. What it does is return `x`.

Comment: @Gregor so, if I have `get <- function() x` is equivalent to have `get <- function() {x}`?

Comment: Thanks @Roland, I think I've understood well lexical scoping, neverthless int his case my question is about a syntax issue.

Comment: See `help("{")` and [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Control-structures). `{` is a function that combines expressions and returns the result of the last expression. If there is only one expression, there is no need for `{`.

Comment: @Mauro yes. You can always leave out the `{}` if the expression is only one line long. (with `function`, `if`, `for`, etc...)

Comment: Thank you both for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `?"function"` help page, the syntax for a function is

```
function( arglist ) expr
```

So you just need to put a single expression after the arguments in parenthesis. For example,

```
foo <- function(x) sqrt(x)
```

Is perfectly fine. The thing is that most functions need to do a bit more work than run a single expression. So in R, `{` is basically a function that creates a collection of expressions. (See the `?"{"` help page.) It returns the value of the last expression in the block. So these are the same

```
foo <- function(x) {x}
foo <- function(x) x
```